# Text cropping when using overflow: hidden

Tags: overflow, css

i have this simple html and css http://jsfiddle.net/JVfVv/1/

Problem is the text is being cropped under safari/chrome/firefox on mac. Removing overflow: hidden corrects the problem, however this line is necessary for other reasons. Removing line-height: 1; appears to fix the problem, however i get this from my reset stylesheet, and I don't understad why having it causes a crop.

Can someone explain why this is happening, and how to fix it please? thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To answer the question of why this happens, I think the key is this particular phrase from the [Fonts section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-size-props) of the CSS 2.1 spec (emphasis mine):

> The font size corresponds to the em square, a concept used in typography. **Note that certain glyphs may bleed outside their em squares.**

The `line-height: 1` declaration sets the height of the paragraph to the same height as the `font-size` (since the paragraph only has one line).  The fact that some characters are cut off implies that their glyphs bleed outside their em squares (I don't know how to definitively prove that this is true; I'm just speculating based on the evidence).

As for a solution, the most straightforward solution would be to use a larger `line-height` setting, such as 1.1 or 1.2.

Comment: line-height's default value is "normal" and is about 1.2 depending on font https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height

Comment: This solution makes sense but I wonder why "overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: visible;" still cuts off the glyphs?

Comment: @gerryster, an interesting question made more interesting by the fact that removing "overflow-x: hidden" seems to stop the text from cutting off (http://jsfiddle.net/URuAL/1/). I suggest you ask a new question. I really don't know what's going on.

Comment: @gerryster, never mind, I found the same question asked and answered here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11161216/249624

Answer (score -1):

You can set the `height` in CSS which solves the problem?

```
p {
    line-height: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial; font-size: 30px;
    height:32px; /* this appears to solve the problem */
}​
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/JVfVv/4/

Comment: -1 this is a horrible solution, would only work for single lines of text, and the P element is for paragraphs... http://jsfiddle.net/JVfVv/17/

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to fix it on safari.